# template template class specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am just learning about Template Template class specialisation. Not a big problem to explain in detail. From my understanding `std::uniform_int_distribution` is a template whereas `std::uniform_int_distribution<Type>` is the full specialisation of `uniform_int_distribution` giving a type. I pass this in the specialisation class template as follows below

---

**Main class**

```
template <template <class> class Distribution,
    class Type,
    class Engine = std::mt19937>
class random_gen
{
    ....
}
```

**specialization of class**

```
template <class Type, class Engine>
class random_gen<std::uniform_real_distribution<Type>, Type, Engine>
{
    ...
}
```

---

*the error that occurs is*:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class Distribution, class Type, class Engine> class random_gen'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specialization still needs to be a template template argument. You passed in a full type. You want:

```
template <class Type, class Engine>
class random_gen<std::uniform_real_distribution, Type, Engine>
{
    ...
};
```

Just `std::uniform_real_distribution`, not `std::uniform_distribution<Type>`.